# Triple fault in home grown kernel

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel

I am trying to write a kernel, mostly for entertainment purposes, and I am running into a problem were I believe it is triple faulting.  Everything worked before I attempted to enable paging.  The code that is breaking is this:

```
void switch_page_directory(page_directory_t *dir){

 current_directory = dir;
 asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr3":: "r"(&dir->tablesPhysical));

 u32int cr0;
 asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0": "=r"(cr0));

 cr0 |= 0x80000000;//enable paging
 asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0":: "r"(cr0)); //this line breaks


}//switch page directory
```

I have been following a variety of tutorials / documents for this but the one I am using to paging is thus http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/6.-Paging.html .  I am not sure what other code will be useful in figuring this out but if there is more I should provide I will be more than happy to do so.

Edit=====

I believe the CS,DS and SS are selecting correct entries here's the code used to set them

```
global gdt_flush     
extern gp            
gdt_flush:

    lgdt [gp]        ; Load the GDT with our 'gp' which is a special pointer
    mov ax, 0x10      ; 0x10 is the offset in the GDT to our data segment

    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    jmp 0x08:flush2   ; 0x08 is the offset to our code segment: Far jump!

flush2:
    ret               ; Returns back to the C code!
```

and here's the gdt struct itself

```
struct gdt_entry{
    unsigned short limit_low;
    unsigned short base_low;
    unsigned char base_middle;
    unsigned char access;
    unsigned char granularity;
    unsigned char base_high;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct gdt_ptr{
    unsigned short limit;
    unsigned int base;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct gdt_entry gdt[5];
struct gdt_ptr gp;
```

The IDT is very similar to this.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you execute the problematic line?

Comment: The virtual machine restarts itself and im brought back to the boot loader

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here: many things could have gone wrong, particularly if you're mixing stuff from a variety of tutorials.  How have you set up the GDT?  Are CS, DS and SS (at least) all selecting appropriate GDT entries?  What about the IDT?  Have the page tables been correctly set up for an identity mapping?  What virtual machine environment are you running this in?

Comment: I added more code as an edit to make it more legible than as a comment.  Thank for replying I wasn't entirely sure what I should post that might be useful. The virtual machine I am using is qemu.  The page tables have been set up for an identity mapping but I'm not entirely sure on the correctly part I'll look into that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDT: you don't say what the *contents* of the GDT entries are, but the stuff you've shown looks fairly similar to the [earlier part of the tutorial you linked to](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/4.-The%20GDT%20and%20IDT.html) and if you've set up the entries in the same way, then all should be well (i.e. flat segment mapping with a ring 0 code segment for CS, ring 0 data segment for everything else, both with a base of 0 and a limit of 4GB).

IDT: probably doesn't matter anyway if interrupts are disabled and you're not (yet) expecting to cause page faults.

Page tables: incorrect page tables do seem like the most likely suspect.  Make sure that your identity mapping covers *all* of the code, data and stack memory that you're using (at least).

The source code linked to at the bottom of http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/6.-Paging.html definitely builds something that *does* work correctly with both QEMU and Bochs, so hopefully you can compare what you're doing with what that's doing, and work out what is wrong.

QEMU is good in general, but I would recommend [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) for developing really low-level stuff - it includes (or can be configured to include) a very handy [internal debugger](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html).  e.g. set `reset_on_triple_fault=0` on the `cpu:` line of the config file, set a breakpoint in the `switch_page_directory()` code, run to the breakpoint, then single step instructions and see what happens...

Comment: Thank you I'll set up bochs I only used qemu because that's what the lab at my university had installed.

Comment: one more question if you know off the top of your head how do i get boch to read a floppy.img I cant do sudo losetup /dev/loop0 floppy.img as I am not on a machine I have sudo access to

Comment: You can just point it at a file rather than a loopback device.  e.g. `floppya: 1_44=floppy.img, status=inserted` .

Comment: @bschaffer13 Did you find a solution to this problem? I am following the same tutorial and got exactly the same error and I am experiencing trouble getting bochs to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can link qemu to a gdb debugger session via the remote debugger tools in gdb.  This can be done by issuing the following commands:

```
qemu -s [optional arguments]
```

Then inside your gdb session, open your kernel executable, and after setting a break-point in your `switch_page_directory()` function, type in the following command at the gdb prompt:

```
target remote localhost:1234
```

You can then single-step through your kernel at the breakpoint, and see where your triple-fault is taking place.

Another step to consider is to actually install some default exception handlers in your IDT ... the reason you are triple-faulting is because an exception is being thrown by the CPU, but there is no proper exception handler available to handle it.  Thus with some default handlers installed, especially the double-fault handler, you can effectively stop the kernel without going into a triple-fault that automatically resets the PC.

Finally, make sure you have re-programmed the PIC before going into protected mode ... otherwise the default hardware interrupts it's programmed to trigger from the BIOS in real-mode will now trigger the exception interrupts in protected mode.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem with paging tutorial.But after some searching i found the solution it was happening because **as soon as paging is enabled, all address become virtual** and to solve it we must map the virtual addresses to the same physical addresses so they refer to the same thing and this is called **identity mapping.**

you can follow this [link](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev18.html) for further help in implementing Identity Maping.

and one more thing you have memset the newly allocated space to zero because it may contain garbage values and memset was not done in tutorial it will work on bochs because it set the space to zero for you but other emulator(qemu) and real hardware are so kind.